# adding onfocus event handler to every element

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an undefined message on all of my handlers. I want to bind a handler to every element and want to output the value. What is wrong with this code? Thanks!

```
 for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++ ){
  document.forms[0].elements[i].onfocus = test(this);
 }

 function test(ele){
  alert(ele.value);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a function. At the moment you are assigning the return value of `test(window)` which is `undefined`.

```
onfocus = test;
```

Then reference the element inside the function:

```
function test(){
    alert(this.value);
}
```

Comment: You must. Otherwise you call the function. Inside an event handler, `this` will be the element to which the event is attached. So replace `evt` with `this` inside the function.

Comment: you should qualify that, in other cases `= test(this);` is perfectly valid.  He should omit `this`, *for this approach*, but that shouldn't be a global statement, there are tons of valid closure cases with that signature :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change both the assignment and the function, since the element will no longer be passed in as a parameter, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++ ){
  document.forms[0].elements[i].onfocus = test;
}
function test(){
  alert(this.value);
}
```

As an event handler, `this` inside `test` will refer to the element you're dealing with, so just get the value from that.

---

The alternative version of your current approach would be the same `test` method, but with an anonymous function wrapper to pass the element itself as a parameter:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++ ){
  ddocument.forms[0].elements[i].onfocus = function() { test(this); };
}
function test(ele){
  alert(ele.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As both Nick and David pointed out, the way you assign the event handler is not correct. However, to achieve what you are trying (pass in a context) you can use a delegate function. Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++ ){
  var ele = document.forms[0].elements[i];
  ele.onfocus = delegate(ele, test);
}

function delegate(obj, handler) {
  return function () {
    handler.call(obj);
  }
}

function test() {
  alert(this.value);
}
```

What the `delegate` function does, is call your handler function setting the context of `this`. See the documentation for the [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for further information. For even further reading, I recommend [The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) and [Introduction to events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) on Quirksmode.